# what is the procedure to install gstreamer along with opencv on ubuntu server edition

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-12.04, gstreamer

I am trying to install opencv , gstreamer onto ubuntu server but as ubuntu server edition differs considerable from desktop edition there are lots of libraries which are not installed on fresh copy of server edition so I am facing various dependency problems with it.

Do anyone know the systematic and step by step guide for this ?

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install  will also pull the required dependencies.

Comment: Then file a bug to ubuntu. What is broken/missing?